# Background image not displaying when using the class inside section

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have two section in the page. I am displaying the background image which is displaying in the first section because I added the class like this `<section class="back_bg banner_bg"></section>`

Now I am displaying the same image (or maybe another image) and this time I added the class inside section like this

```
<section><div class="back_bg banner_bg"></div></section>
```

but this time my image is not displaying. If I set `display: initial;` to the section then it's working but it also removes the background color of the content.

> Note: I don't want to use the specific height.

Any idea why this issue is happening?

**First section**

```css
html,body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .banner_bg{
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        background-position: center;
        min-height:100%;
       }

    .back_bg{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)),url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    }
    section{background-color: #fff;padding-top: 30px;padding-bottom: 30px;}
```

```html
    <section class="back_bg banner_bg"></section>
```

**Second Section**

```css
html,body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .banner_bg{
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        background-position: center;
        min-height:100%;
       }

    .back_bg{
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)),url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    }
    section{background-color: #fff;padding-top: 30px;padding-bottom: 30px;}
```

```html
 <section>
    <div class="back_bg banner_bg"></div>
     <p style="color: #fff;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
     tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
     quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
     consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
     cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
     proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </section>
```

Comment: @MrLister, Yes, because I added the class inside section. If I add the class with a section like first one then it's working.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't paying attention; there are supposed to be two images in the snippet.

Comment: background image should be a background to something. if nothing inside, no need of background

Comment: @MrLister, Yes there are two images in the snippet. I am using two section and image is displaying for first section.

Comment: OK, so then the question becomes, what are you trying to achieve? What height does the div in the second section have to have? Would 100vh instead of 100% do the trick?

Comment: @MrLister, Question is, why I am not able to display the background image when I am adding the class inside section(second section).

Comment: @MrLister, why my second section is not working.?

Comment: @NarendraVerma Because the second section doesn't have a specific `height`, so the browser can't calculate the `min-height` of the div inside. The height remains 0.

Comment: @MrLister, Yes, right, The browser can't calculate the min-height. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Like I said, that depends on what you want to achieve. Ankit's solution looks nice.

Comment: @MrLister, I just want to display the background image inside section

Answer (score 2):

The min-height of first section in your code is specified in percentage. Its resulting height is calculated with respect to the height of the its containing block, i.e. body.

Now, since you haven't specified the height of the second section, its height will be calculated according to the contents in it. Hence, it does not have its own height.

The div's resulting height is being calculated according to its containing block(i.e. the second section), which does not have a height of its own.
Hence, you have to specifically give some height to the div. Setting min-height won't help.

For display: initial explanation, read:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial

Read more:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.banner_bg{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-position: center;
    min-height:100%;
   }

.back_bg{
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)),url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg');
background-attachment: fixed;
}
section{background-color: #fff;padding-top: 30px;padding-bottom: 30px;}
```

```html
<!--first section-->
<section class="back_bg banner_bg"></section>
<!--end first section-->

<!--section section-->
<section>
<div class="back_bg banner_bg"><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg" height="300" style="visibility:hidden" /></div>
 <div style="color: #fff;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</section>
<!--section section-->
```

Comment: position: absolute will display the image I tried  before  but it displays very small, something like.250px;

Comment: You should provide examples as part of your answer

Comment: @NarendraVerma is this one is helpful

Comment: @Ankit, You added the img tag that I know, I need to display form background.

Answer (score 0):

Background image should be something that backgrounds something. So for a block element to have a background, it should have some children in it.

> Note: adding text directly inside a div is a bad practice. You should
>   wrap it with `p` or `span`

```css
html,body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.banner_bg{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-position: center;
    min-height:100%;
   }

.back_bg{
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)),url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg');
background-attachment: fixed;
}
section{background-color: #fff;padding-top: 30px;padding-bottom: 30px;}
```

```html
<!--first section-->
<section class="back_bg banner_bg"></section>
<!--end first section-->

<!--section section-->
<section>
<div class="back_bg banner_bg">
 <span style="color: #fff;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span></div>
</section>
<!--section section-->
```

Comment: I don't want to display any text over the background image.

Comment: What do you mean by "Note: adding text directly inside a div is a bad practice. You should wrap it with p or span"? Who are you quoting there?

Comment: @Narendra Verma

Comment: @Adeebbasheer, I am here to get the help. I already inform you that I don't want to add the text.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your second section to be visible you need to edit your styles like this:

```css
html,body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .banner_bg{
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            background-position: center;
            min-height:100%;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 0;
           }
    
        .back_bg{
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)),url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg');
        background-attachment: fixed;
        }
        section{background-color: #fff;padding-top: 30px;padding-bottom: 30px; position: relative;}
        section p, section span { position: relative;
        z-index: 1; display: block; padding: 2em 0; }
```

```html
<!--first section-->
<!--<section class="back_bg banner_bg"></section>-->
<!--end first section-->

<!--section section-->
<section>
<div class="back_bg banner_bg">
 <span style="color: #fff;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
 quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
 consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
 cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
 proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</span></div>
</section>
<!--section section-->
```

Comment: Can you create the jsfiddle link? Because I tried the position: absolute; and Image is also displaying but it is displaying very small height.

Comment: @NarendraVerma I've edited my answer, I think there are a lot of unused css properties, I mean, they're not required to achieve what you want.

Comment: You have to comment the first section and then check the output  Because I tried the position: absolute; and Image is also displaying but it is displaying very small height

Comment: @NarendraVerma I've commented the first section. There's no possible way that the container gets the height of the background image you set; What you can do is: display your text elements as `block` and add a `padding` top and bottom, this way the background image is going to scale to fit the background. I've edited the answer